# How to aggregate values from a list and display in react native app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list which I get from firebase and displaying those values in the UI using SwipeListView.

The list data contains details like: coin price, count of coins purchased, total cost of the coins as price,count and amount. And some other fields.

Now, I want to make aggregate of all the coins and display in the text field. But the aggregation I am not able to set.

I tried creating two variables and setting those using hooks but getting error as

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Can you please suggest the approach please. Below is my code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Keyboard,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph } from "react-native-paper";
import { SwipeListView } from "react-native-swipe-list-view";
import styles from "./styles";
import { firebase } from "../../firebase/config";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

export default function OrderList(props) {
  const LeftContent = (props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />;

  const [orderText, setOrderText] = useState("");
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  const orderRef = firebase.firestore().collection("orders");
  const userID = props.route.params.userID;
  const coin = props.route.params.coin;
  let totalCost = 0;
  let totalCount = 0;

  const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useState[""];
  const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState[""];
  const [averageValue, setAverageValue] = useState("");
  //averageValue = (totalCost / totalCount).toString();

  useEffect(() => {
    orderRef
      .where("authorID", "==", userID)
      .where("name", "==", coin)
      .orderBy("createdAt")
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          const newOrders = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const order = doc.data();
            order.id = doc.id;
            newOrders.push(order);
          });
          setOrders(newOrders);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAverageValue(
      (parseFloat(totalCost) / parseFloat(totalCount)).toString()
    );
  }, [totalCount, totalCost]);

  const onAddButtonPress = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate("CreateOrder", {
      coin: coin,
      userID: userID,
      orderRef,
    });
  };

  const renderOrder = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log("----------------------");
    console.log(item.createdAt.toDate().toString());
    console.log("----------------------");
    setTotalCost(parseFloat(totalCost) + parseFloat(item.price));
    setTotalCount(parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat(item.count));
    console.log(totalCost);
    console.log(totalCount);

    return (
      <View style={styles1.rowFront}>
        <Text>
          {index}. {item.price} {item.amount} {item.count}
          {"\n" + item.createdAt.toDate().toString()}
        </Text>

        <Icon name={"flight-takeoff"} />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onAddButtonPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Click here to create new order..</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>Average: {averageValue}</Text>
      {orders && (
        <SwipeListView
          data={orders}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={renderOrder}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  rowFront: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderBottomWidth: 0.25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 50,
  },
  rowBack: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDD",
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  backRightBtn: {
    alignItems: "center",
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    width: 75,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Modified code with normal variables and useEffect linked to them to change average.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Keyboard,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph } from "react-native-paper";
import { SwipeListView } from "react-native-swipe-list-view";
import styles from "./styles";
import { firebase } from "../../firebase/config";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

export default function OrderList(props) {
  const LeftContent = (props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />;

  const [orderText, setOrderText] = useState("");
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  const orderRef = firebase.firestore().collection("orders");
  const userID = props.route.params.userID;
  const coin = props.route.params.coin;
  let totalCost = 0;
  let totalCount = 0;

  //const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useState[""];
  //const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState[""];
  const [averageValue, setAverageValue] = useState("");
  //averageValue = (totalCost / totalCount).toString();

  useEffect(() => {
    orderRef
      .where("authorID", "==", userID)
      .where("name", "==", coin)
      .orderBy("createdAt")
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          const newOrders = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const order = doc.data();
            order.id = doc.id;
            newOrders.push(order);
          });
          setOrders(newOrders);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAverageValue(
      (parseFloat(totalCost) / parseFloat(totalCount)).toString()
    );
  }, [totalCount, totalCost]);

  const onAddButtonPress = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate("CreateOrder", {
      coin: coin,
      userID: userID,
      orderRef,
    });
  };

  const renderOrder = ({ item, index }) => {
    console.log("----------------------");
    console.log(item.createdAt.toDate().toString());
    console.log("----------------------");
    //setTotalCost(parseFloat(totalCost) + parseFloat(item.price));
    //setTotalCount(parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat(item.count));
    totalCost = parseFloat(totalCost) + parseFloat(item.price);
    totalCount = parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat(item.count);

    console.log(totalCost);
    console.log(totalCount);

    return (
      <View style={styles1.rowFront}>
        <Text>
          {index}. {item.price} {item.amount} {item.count}
          {"\n" + item.createdAt.toDate().toString()}
        </Text>

        <Icon name={"flight-takeoff"} />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onAddButtonPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Click here to create new order..</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>Average: {averageValue}</Text>
      {orders && (
        <SwipeListView
          data={orders}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={renderOrder}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  rowFront: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderBottomWidth: 0.25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 50,
  },
  rowBack: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDD",
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  backRightBtn: {
    alignItems: "center",
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    width: 75,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

.

thanks @jnpdx it is working now. Based on your inputs, my changes.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Keyboard,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import { Avatar, Button, Card, Title, Paragraph } from "react-native-paper";
import { SwipeListView } from "react-native-swipe-list-view";
import styles from "./styles";
import { firebase } from "../../firebase/config";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { createIconSetFromFontello } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export default function OrderList(props) {
  const LeftContent = (props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />;

  const [orderText, setOrderText] = useState("");
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  const orderRef = firebase.firestore().collection("orders");
  const userID = props.route.params.userID;
  const coin = props.route.params.coin;

  //averageValue = (totalCost / totalCount).toString();
  const [averageValue, setAverageValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    orderRef
      .where("authorID", "==", userID)
      .where("name", "==", coin)
      .orderBy("createdAt")
      .onSnapshot(
        (querySnapshot) => {
          const newOrders = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const order = doc.data();
            order.id = doc.id;
            newOrders.push(order);
          });
          setOrders(newOrders);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //calculate and set anything like totalCost, averageValue, etc here
    console.log("---came to orders effect---");
    //console.log(orders);
    let totalCost = 0;
    let totalCount = 0;
    orders.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log(item);
      console.log(index);
      totalCost += parseFloat(item.amount);
      totalCount += parseFloat(item.count);
    });
    setAverageValue((totalCost / totalCount).toString());
  }, [orders]);
  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    let avg = (parseFloat(totalCost) / parseFloat(totalCount)).toString();
    console.log("Avg:" + avg);
    setAverageValue(avg);
  }, [totalCount, totalCost]);
*/
  const onAddButtonPress = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate("CreateOrder", {
      coin: coin,
      userID: userID,
      orderRef,
    });
  };

  const renderOrder = ({ item, index }) => {
    //console.log("----------------------");
    //console.log(item.createdAt.toDate().toString());
    //console.log("----------------------");
    //setTotalCost(parseFloat(totalCost) + parseFloat(item.price));
    //setTotalCount(parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat(item.count));
    //totalCost = parseFloat(totalCost) + parseFloat(item.price);
    //totalCount = parseFloat(totalCount) + parseFloat(item.count);

    //console.log(totalCost);
    //console.log(totalCount);

    return (
      <View style={styles1.rowFront}>
        <Text>
          {index}. {item.price} {item.amount} {item.count}
          {"\n" + item.createdAt.toDate().toString()}
        </Text>

        <Icon name={"flight-takeoff"} />
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onAddButtonPress}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Click here to create new order..</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {orders.length === 0 && (
        <Text>Please order some coins in currency: {coin}</Text>
      )}
      {orders && orders.length > 0 && (
        <>
          <Text>Average Value: {averageValue}</Text>
          <SwipeListView
            data={orders}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={renderOrder}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  rowFront: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderBottomWidth: 0.25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: 50,
  },
  rowBack: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#DDD",
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    paddingLeft: 15,
  },
  backRightBtn: {
    alignItems: "center",
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    width: 75,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    right: 0,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `useState` hook functions (`setTotalCost` and `setTotalCount`) *inside* your render function. This will end up causing issues like the error that you're seeing or even worse, an infinite loop.

Instead of calling these when rendering, use `useEffect` instead and perform the necessarily calculations whenever the related dependencies change. It looks like you're already doing that for `setAverageValue`, so you're familiar with what's involved in doing that.

Update, based on comments:

```
useEffect(() => {
 //calculate and set anything like totalCost, averageValue, etc here 
}, [orders])
```

Comment: but the setAverageValue is not updating its value on the UI. So I tried keeping inside the render with hooks but that giving this error. I tried keeping the totalCost and totalCount as variables and tried to calculate average from the useEffect and loading that in the view. But it is not updating the content there.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying in the comment above. The fact is, you can't set hooks like that in your render method. Use `useEffect` instead. If you've tried that and it "is not updating the content", show the code where you made an attempt.

Comment: i appended to the question as "modified code" at the end. Can you check that and reply back. THe console.log is printing the value but the useEffect is not fetching the values, either they are state variables or normal variables.

Comment: You got rid of `totalCount` and `totalCost`, so now the `useEffect` will never run because it has no dependencies. I'd tell you exactly what to change, but from reading your code, it's not immediately obvious to me what's supposed to be happening there or where the values are coming from.

Comment: renderOrder will render function for SwipeListView, which passes orders as a list to it.The orders list is received from firebase and contains multiple orders with name,cost,price per coin. All the orders are rendered in the SwipeListView. I need average cost of all the orders. Formula will be average= totalCost/totalPrice. And totalCost = sum of all cost fields in orders, totalCount=sum of all count fields in the orders. So, I need aggregate value for the all the items in the SwipeListVIew.

Comment: Okay, so when you get your Firebase query back, `orders` is set. So, you should have a `useEffect` with a dependency on `orders` where all of your calculations for your costs, averages, etc are done whenever `orders` changes.

Comment: Aggregate value, not individual order value. in this component i am getting orders as a param. Need  only the total aggregate value. so where is the dependency now then, my complete list code given above, can you tell what exactly you are trying to say.Just saying the term useEffect is not helping here.

Comment: I'm not just "saying the term" `useEffect` and I'm sorry you feel it's not helpful. I *am* trying to explain exactly what I mean. I've added a snippet to show you what a `useEffect` with a dependency on `orders` would look like, where you'd do all over your calculations. It's up to you to do that part, though. If you see that and still feel like this hasn't been helpful at all, let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Need one more help from you, this averagevalue, instead of printing in the same page, I want to return it back to the component/function which earlier call this component. Its like first page will be list of coins, and second page is list of orders. From orders, I want to calculate the average value(which done now), this should be returned to the list of coins and first page should display in the individual coins(average value)

Comment: Can you post your comment on this new question also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848853/how-to-display-a-value-back-in-parent-component-in-react-native